# Можно ли передать из EditText в TextView не только текст, но и цвет текста, его размер и толщину?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textview

У меня в активности есть ЭдитТекст, где я ввожу текст и изменяю его параметры (textSize, textColor,bold/italic) и фон. Всё работает.

Дальше по нажатию кнопки текст с параметрами должен передаваться в TextView в виджете. Я сделала код для передачи текста и фона из EditText в TextView и он работает, но как передать параметры текста я не знаю. Пробовала сделать по аналогии, но
с textSize у меня проблема с float, а с textColor то, что в ЭдитТекст нет метода getTextColor() и я не могу получить последнее значение textColor.
Можно ли вообще передать текст с параметрами из
ЭдитТекст в ТекстВьев?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, у вас есть `editText` и `textView`:

```java
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

Чтобы для `textView` задать размер текста, цвет текст и стиль такие же, как у `editText`, воспользуйтесь соответствующими методами:

```java
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, editText.getTextSize());
textView.setTextColor(editText.getCurrentTextColor());
textView.setTypeface(editText.getTypeface());
```

Обратите внимание, чтобы правильно выставить размер текста, необходимо первым аргументом передать константу `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX`, так как `getTextSize()` возвращает размер в пикселях.

Результат:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Большое спасибо, с размером и цветом текста всё получилось. Но с typefase ничего не получается, потому что у меня ситуация сложнее. Мне нужно получить значение typefase из Эдит Текст в активности, сохранить это значение в SharedPreferences и передать в ТекстВьев в виджете. Я получаю значение из ЭдитТекст в Typeface, а передать могу только в int. И я не понимаю, что с этим делать. Видимо, это уже другой вопрос, но если Вы такое делали, подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить typefase в SharedPreferences?